# Computation of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x \, \arctan x}{x}dx$

Tags: integration

I found the following integral without an answer and tried to compute it. According to [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=definite+integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22variable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22rangestart%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22definite+integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22cos%28x%29*arctan%28x%29%2Fx%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22rangeend%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22) it´s equal to

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x \, \arctan x}{x}dx=0,344608$$

In order to evaluate it, I introduced a parameter, and considered the version

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (x) \, \arctan (ax)}{x}dx$$

$$I^{\prime}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (x) \, x}{x(1+a^2x^2)}dx$$

$$I^{\prime}(a)=\frac{1}{a^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (x) }{\frac{1}{a^2}+x^2}dx$$

$$I^{\prime}(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{a}}}{a}$$

$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^a \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t}}}{t}dt$$

in the last step, if we let $a=1$ we get the original integral

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t}}}{t}dt$$

letting $t=\frac{1}{t}$, the integral becomes

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$

$$I(1)=-\frac{\pi}{2} E_{i}(-1)$$

Which agrees numerically with the original integral.

---

We can try integrating by parts the last integral

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(e^{-u}\ln(u)\Big|_1^{\infty}+\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-u}\ln(u)du \right)$$

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-u}\ln(u)du $$

Comment: What on earth is your question?

Comment: Sorry, the question got confused because I kept editing it. Originally I was looking for a closed form solution. I found out that there is not. However it can be expressed in terms of exponential integral function.

Comment: That is a closed form solution.

Comment: in terms of elementary functions

Answer (score 2):

for the last one:
$$\int_0^a\frac{\exp(-1/t)}{t}dt\stackrel{u=1/t}=\int_{\infty}^{1/a}\frac{\exp(-u)}{1/u}\frac{-du}{u^2}=\int_{1/a}^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$
which can be defined in terms of the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, and updated the question, thank you. I may try integration by parts for the last integral.

Comment: the reason why the last integral is defined as such is because integration by parts will not work, but best of luck